# Dynamically change background color with animated transition

Tags: java, android, animation, random, colors

I'm trying to generate a random color and set it as the background at the rate of 3 seconds. I have created a `thread` that will handle this change, now I would like to add a transition between the color changes to make it blend well.

As a reference, take a look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.tunglabs.dynamiccolorsflashlight.lite).

EDIT: 
I've tried using an `ObjectAnimator` and `ArgbEvaluator` in a loop with a 3 second transition period, but the screen keeps flashing in a strobe-like way that will just give you a headache. Besides that, the colors change just fine and everything else is perfect. Could somebody run this and see what could be going wrong?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public int color1, color2, red1, red2, blue1, blue2, green1, green2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000); // I've also tried 1000 and 4000, same issue.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    //generate color 1
                        red1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        green1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        blue1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        color1 = 0xff << 24 | (red1 << 16) |
                                (green1 << 8) | blue1;


                    //generate color 2

                        red2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        green2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        blue2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        color2 = 0xff << 24 | (red2 << 16) |
                                (green2 << 8) | blue2;

                    //start animation
                        View v = findViewById(R.id.view);
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", color1, color2);


                        anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                        anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                        anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
                        anim.setDuration(3000);
                        anim.start();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

EDIT: I've narrowed it down and found the ".setRepeatMode" was causing the problem. I still don't have a fix. By changing the "Reverse" to something else (Infinite or other provided options) it prevents the animation from happening. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

ALSO, does anybody know a better way to generate more vibrant colors? Everything I looked into is outdated.

Comment: What happens, when you run this code?

Comment: That thread plus reversing the animation will not go too well. Have a look at this and see if it's what you want https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6673439 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly except for one thing: Every 3 seconds, you are randomly generating **2** colors. So, this is what's happening:

> **1st iteration**:
>
> color1 is generated
>
> color2 is generated
>
> View's background is set to color1. And then the background changes
>   from color1 to color2.
>
> // All's good
>
> **2nd iteration**:
>
> There's a new color1
>
> There's a new color2
>
> View's background is set to **new color1**. Immediate change causes
>   the strobe light effect. And then the background changes from new
>   color1 to new color2.

What you should do to fix this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Generate color1 before starting the thread
    red1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
    green1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
    blue1 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
    color1 = 0xff << 24 | (red1 << 16) |
                          (green1 << 8) | blue1;


    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    //generate color 2

                        red2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        green2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        blue2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                        color2 = 0xff << 24 | (red2 << 16) |
                                (green2 << 8) | blue2;

                    //start animation
                        View v = findViewById(R.id.view);
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", color1, color2);


                        anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                        anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                        anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
                        anim.setDuration(3000);
                        anim.start();

                        // Now set color1 to color2
                        // This way, the background will go from
                        // the previous color to the next color
                        // smoothly
                        color1 = color2;

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

So, from second iteration onwards, the starting color should be the same as the ending color for the previous iteration. Initialize/generate color1 only once: before starting the thread. After `anim.start()`, add:

```
color1 = color2;
```

Also, note that you are creating a new `ObjectAnimator` *every* 3 seconds:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", color1, color2);
```

So, the following statements have no effect:

```
anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
```

Here's what I would recommend:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    public int color1, color2, red1, red2, blue1, blue2, green1, green2;

    View v;

    ObjectAnimator anim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // White or whatever color background R.id.view
        // has at the beginning
        color1 = 0xffffffff;

        v = findViewById(R.id.llMain);

        // We haven't initialized color2 yet. Will set this later
        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", color1);

        anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

        anim.setDuration(3000);


        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            //generate color 2

                            red2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                            green2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                            blue2 = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
                            color2 = 0xff << 24 | (red2 << 16) |
                                    (green2 << 8) | blue2;

                            // Update the color values
                            anim.setIntValues(color1, color2);

                            anim.start();

                            // Order the colors
                            color1 = color2;

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

This way, you're creating an ObjectAnimator object once, and updating the color values every 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the quality answer, it works! I'll award the bounty when it will allow me in 33 min.

Comment: @Collin You're welcome. That's the speediest bounty delivery I have seen. Thank you.

Comment: I got it to work but I needed to move it to my primary app so I copied the xml and java class over and now the ObjectAnimator doesn't work correctly. It doesn't have the fade effect that I got to work before. I made sure I'm on API 11 and I'm clueless why this wouldn't work in another project. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @Collin It will be hard to take a guess at what's getting broken during the transference. Off the top of my head: Try setting the duration to a little less than the sleep value, say: `anim.setDuration(2900)`. Also, some of the methods that belong to `ObjectAnimator` require API 14. But, the code above doesn't use any of them. So, that can't be the issue. Would it be possible for you to post the updated code? Better yet, post a new question with the updated code, and the layout you are using. Leave me a comment here with the link and I will take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071825/objectanimator-not-fading-background-colors-in-a-thread

Comment: I've tried it with API 16 and changed the duration to something below the thread time. I still can't manage to figure it out after awhile of messing with it.

Comment: its owsome but how to stop it by click on button or other view ??

Comment: @VishalPatel Thanks, Vishal. This is a very old answer, and I would suggest that you use a `Handler` instead of a `Thread`. Using a `Handler`, you can post a `Runnable` with `postDelayed(Runnable, long)`. This way, when you need it to stop, call `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to stop the animation.

Comment: i was also looking for the same but unfortunatly can't use it. Is it available in Angular/Jquery or Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

How about use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) w/ [ArgbEvaluator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html). Using ObjectAnimator, you can animate any property easily if the object has a proper setter method in camel case(in the form of set()). In your case, View has `setBackgroundColor`, so you can try this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.mask2);
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
anim.setDuration(3000);
anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
anim.start();
```

For more general & detail description about Property Animation:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator

Unfortunately, this new api is only supported API11+, so if you concern about compatibility issue, you can try to use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library written by JakeWharton.

Comment: Ahh I see what's happening. I tried to do this dynamically with random colors but the transition causes a strobe-like effect and will basically give any user a seizure. Can you take a look at the new code on my edited post?

Comment: I've narrowed it down and found the ".setRepeatMode" was causing the problem. I still don't have a fix- by changing the "Reverse" to something else it prevents the animation from happening. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative how to change the color of the background;

```
    ColorDrawable[] color = { new ColorDrawable(Color.RED), new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE) };
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    trans.startTransition(3000);
```

This approach also has methods like trans.reverseTransition(duration) available.